# How to refine ultrasonic readings

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

I am trying to filter ultrasonic readings using averaging technique. I've also used `millis()` to measure time from start so that I can calculate readings up to 1 second and average them. I've re-initialized the `elapsedTime` variable each time to zero in the loop but again when the program execution hits this code the time starts from the time it was before. Is there any way to solve this problem?

This is the code:

```cpp
NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); // NewPing setup of pins and maximum distance.

int dist, ctr, filteredDist;
long rawValue = 0;
unsigned long StartTime = millis();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // Open serial monitor at 115200 baud to see ping results.
}
//********************************************************************************************************************
void loop() {
  delay(500);
  unsigned long elapsedTime = StartTime;

  while (elapsedTime < 1000) {
    ctr++;
    dist = sonar.ping_cm();
    rawValue += dist;
    elapsedTime = millis();
  }
  filteredDist = rawValue / ctr;
  Serial.println(filteredDist);
}
```

Comment: You're looking at absolute times (the time since boot). You need to look at *time differences*. That means performing subtraction.

Comment: @Majenko thanks for your reply. It would be great if you would slightly modify the code.

Comment: I can't "slightly" modify the code. It needs a complete rewrite. There's not a lot that can be salvaged there except the ping code.

Comment: Look at the BlinkWithoutDelay example, and consider using a library for the averaging - such as my [Average](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/Average) library.

Answer (score 1):

`elapsedTime=millis();` sets `elapsedTime` equal to the current value of `millis()`, which in the sketch above is the total time since the Uno powered up.  Thus  `elapsedTime` will exceed 1000 any time after the first second of execution, in which case the `while` won't do anything.

Instead say `elapsedTime=millis() - StartTime;` within the loop.  Whenever you want to start the averaging cycle again, say `StartTime = millis();`.

If your only use of `elapsedTime` is to control the `while` loop, get rid of that variable; instead of  `while(elapsedTime < 1000)`, say `while(millis()-StartTime < 1000)`.